# cmake propagate dependencies using find_package

Tags: c++, cmake

As a simple example: there are two libraries and one executable.
Both libraries are `SHARED` (i.e. a .so file). One is called *libMain* and one is called *libUtil*. *libMain* uses *libUtil* and so does the executable. 
The executable might use *libUtil* on its own but usually it calls a method from *libMain* that does use *libUtil* in its implementation.

So after reading some tutorials and docs about CMake this example seemed fairly straight forward.
There is a simple CMakeLists.txt for each project while *libUtil* links to *libMain* and executable links to *libMain*. (I ommited `target_include_directories` to spare some lines) Same PREFIX_PATH is used by all projects.

## libUtil

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

project(libUtil)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")    
add_library(libUtil SHARED main.cpp)
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/cmake)
```

## libMain

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

project(libMain)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
add_library(libUtil SHARED main.cpp)
find_package(libUtil REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC libUtil)
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/cmake)
```

## executable

```
project(exe)
find_package(libMain REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
add_executable(exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE libMain)
```

However when building the executable I ended up with a linker error, telling exe was **not able to perform -llibUtil**.

I spend quite some time on this already and after reading several posts I found out (or at least I think so..) that I need to provide a **custom libMainConfig.cmake** (I renamed the generated one to libMainTargets.cmake)

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libMainTargets.cmake")

find_package(libUtil REQUIRED)
```

The linker error is gone now and I can run my project. Still I do not understand why I need to do this. I understood there is a difference when handling an already built library. However, as CMake always uses a directory based separation of projects, how and why would I ever build multiple projects in the same CMakeLists.txt? So far I always used `find_package` (which essentialy does add_library IMPORTED, i.e. searches a pre-build library If I am not mistaken) and wanted to propagate its defined dependencies to the "consuming" project. But it seems all of `PUBLIC`, `INTERFACE` and `PRIVATE` from the imported target have no affect in the "consuming" target?

Please be detailed in the explanation and/or point out some references I missed and point out some best practices assuming all projects are either build by myself or are system libraries like boost or JNI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake has a specific function made to propagate `find_package` like this called [`find_dependency`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html). You can use it like that:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(libutil)
```

CMake will not export calls `find_package` in its generated files. You must do it manually with `find_package` or `find_dependency`. The difference is that `find_dependency` will forward `REQUIRED` and `QUIET` correctly.

### Why does CMake tries to send `-llibUtil` to the linker?

When adding something to `target_link_libraries`, there is two cases:

1. The library to link is a target. In this case, the inteface properties are propagated correctly including linking if needed.
2. It's simply a string, there is no targets. In this case, **CMake assumes it's a system library and add the `-l` flag**.

Since linking to `libutil` is a public property of `libmain`, all consumers of `libmain` will also link to `libutil`.

Since calling find package must be done manually, `libutil` is not a target. Linking to a system library is assumed so CMake will make `exe` to a system library named `libutil` which does not exist.

Calling `find_package(libUtil REQUIRED)` will ensure `exe` will consume usage requirements of `libutil` by linking targets instead of libraries.

### How can `libUtil` be a target?

CMake target is not (completely) tied to directories. You can have `GLOBAL` and `IMPORTED` targets, and you can have multiple target by project. Imagine a project that is composed of multiple libraries and executables. An analogy would be that CMake projects are visual studio solution, and CMake targets are visual studio projects.

Now on imported targets. They are meant to represent targets that are already compiled by another project, that you either installed or exported the build tree. Imported target let you consume things from different project just like a normal target, as if you declared it. Targets that are imported are more precise than compiler flags: they carry of course the libary, but also how to link, required compiler flags, include directories and other requirements.

`find_package` and `find_dependency` are meant to find the config file and those contain the imported targets informations. After that, simply linking to it will set include directories, correct linker flags, etc.

A good example of a project exporting multiple targets is SFML, which export different module like sound, graphics and window management as distinct static/dynamic libraries.

### How can this silly mistake can be avoided?

CMake let us use namespaces for targets. When using the namespace syntax, it cannot be a system library. CMake will output an error that the target is not found instead of trying to link to a non-existant library.

```
install(
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
    NAMESPACE libUtil
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/cmake
)
```

And then change linking to this:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC libUtil::libUtil)
```

The convention for namespace name is to use the same name as the package.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Still I am missing 2 points for my understanding:
1.) How would libUtil be a target? As I already mentioned my understanding is that CMake is meant to create a target for each directory/project and CMakeLists.txt file. Hence in any case you would use find_package/depency and look for the Config file, which I did INSTALL? Why would you ever have multiple targets in one project that can be used without find_package?
2.) The namespace is very usefull indeed, but will only point out the error. Whats the best way to solve it?

Comment: @Chris see my edits. I added a paragraph explaining why linking to targets is great and why imported targets are needed to consume libaries from other projects.

Comment: Thanks again. I actually already used SFML.
So final question: Why am I supposed to create a custom Config file than to name the dependencies with find_package/dependecy? Why can't cmake do it on its own as I already told in the CMakeLists.txt that libMain depends on libUtil and PUBLIC uses the target? I read this article first: http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=print_post&node=7593430 and there is no custom Config, just because it's one project with multiple targets in one CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @Chris I think it's simply because it's not implemented, and/or would be a breaking change for some. I don't think CMake can retrace which target comes from what package and I don't think it's even possible CMake can send the right arguments to `find_package` in case of custom paths and such.

Comment: @Chris ah, yes. There is no need to call find_package to use target defined in your project. Only when you have multiple build tree.